# how to search array by string [in ruby]

Tags: ruby

```
def choose_menu
   input = get_input
   #binding.pry
   if input.to_i.between?(1, Recipes.all.length)
           ingredients_Are(input)
       # elsif input == "Amy's Barbecue Chicken Salad"
       #     puts 
       elsif input == "exit" 
           exit_menu
       else
           invalid_Choice
       end
       
   end
```

so i can search a array and pick a string with index number but would like to search by name. Like input "Amy's BBQ" and see the ingredients from that

Comment: You have `"Amy's Barbecue Chicken Salad"` in your array and want to find it when you search for `"Amy's BBQ"`? How should Ruby know that `BBQ` is a synonym for `Barbecue`? What other synonyms do you want to allow?

Comment: sorry, I meant to say I want the user to type exactly "Amy's Barbecue Chicken Salad" to pull up the ingredients for that. I just short handed it for no reason

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a direct search for arrays to catch partial string matches. There is includes? which looks for an item with the same value. I think you are best writing a loop and seeing if each item includes the portion of that string

```
arr1 = [
    "A-aron's Barbecue Chicken Salad",
    "Hank's Barbecue Chicken Salad",
    "Darrel's Barbecue Chicken Salad",
    "Amy's Barbecue Chicken Salad",
    "Franks's Barbecue Chicken Salad"
]

def string_search(array)
    array.each{ |str| return str if str.include?("Amy's Barbecue")}
end

puts string_search(arr1)  # => Amy's Barbecue Chicken Salad
```

Comment: "I think you are best writing a loop" – As a very general rule, whenever you write a loop in Ruby, whether that be a `while` loop, a `for`/`in` loop, or an `#each` iterator, you are doing it wrong. In your case, you have simply re-implemented `Enumerable#find` aka `Enumerable#detect`.

Comment: The more you know. Thank you I didn't even realize!

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
arr1 = [
  "A-aron's Barbecue Chicken Salad",
  "Hank's Barbecue Chicken Salad",
  "Darrel's Barbecue Chicken Salad",
  "Amy's Barbecue Chicken Salad",
  "Franks's Barbecue Chicken Salad"
]
```

Code

```
p arr1.detect { |x| x.match? "Amy's Barbecue" }
```

Output

```
"Amy's Barbecue Chicken Salad"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use grep method if you want only value

```
arr1 = [
    "A-aron's Barbecue Chicken Salad",
    "Hank's Barbecue Chicken Salad",
    "Darrel's Barbecue Chicken Salad",
    "Amy's Barbecue Chicken Salad",
    "Franks's Barbecue Chicken Salad"
]

arr1.grep(/Amy's Barbecue/)
=> ["Amy's Barbecue Chicken Salad"]
```

Try to use collect and with_index method if you want value and index both

```
arr1.collect
    .with_index { |val, index| [index, val] if val.match?(/Amy's Barbecue/) }
    .compact
=> [[3, "Amy's Barbecue Chicken Salad"]]
```